# Do we have aws cli command to wait for ecs service update to start new task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I am using below aws cli command to update my service in ecs with new task definition from Jenkins job.
`aws ecs update-service --cluster xyz --service abc --task-definition=abc.json --force-new-deployment`

This command is updating the service and starting new deployment (creating new task)

**Now, I am looking for aws cli command or a way for my Jenkins job to wait until the newly created task is in RUNNING state.**

I have tried to do list-tasks but not sure how to get the latest task to describe and pull status.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `aws ecs wait services-stable` (documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/wait/services-stable.html)) which will wait for new tasks to be running, and old tasks to be stopped.

Comment: yeah i have looked into this but how do i get the latest task arn once we run the "update-serivce" command ?

I am looking at this command ```aws ecs wait services-stable \
    --cluster MyCluster \
    --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789012:task/a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-44444EXAMPLE```

Comment: You don't need to pass a task arn. Actually I don't think that command even accepts a task arn as a parameter. I think the example in the documentation is a typo or something, because the list of valid parameters does not include `--task`. You would use `wait tasks-running` to wait only for specific tasks. I'm recommending `wait services-stable` specifically because you don't have to specify a specific task.

Comment: @zero86 that's a completely separate thing from what is being discussed in this question/answer. There is no discussion of IP addresses in this question. Ask a separate question if you need help with ECS IP addresses.